# How to prevent ASP.net MVC application authenticating into domain?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity

Today I started my application on my work machine from Visual Studio, and it surprisingly thinks that it authenticated into my work domain. (User.Identity starts to return values about leotsarev@mycompanyname.com)
How I can prevent this from happening?

I don't want my application to auth into domain, only using login/password and my own user DB.

My web.config https://github.com/joinrpg/joinrpg-net/blob/master/Joinrpg/Web.config

.csproj https://github.com/joinrpg/joinrpg-net/blob/master/Joinrpg/JoinRpg.Web.csproj

Comment: Try navigate to 'project properties' of the startup project and disable Windows Authentication.

Comment: ```<IISExpressWindowsAuthentication>disabled</IISExpressWindowsAuthentication>``` doesn't help

Comment: Do you have a Login Controller that sets the logic for authentication?

Comment: @Tiramonium yes, I have already working solution that's deployed 2 years already. I just can't debug it on windows PC that's a part of domain

Comment: Does the login Action have a condition to set the authentication cookie? Something like `FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(model.UserName, model.RememberMe)`. If it does, just add a LINQ query to look for a username-password combination in your Users table before it and add it to the condition to see if any results were found.

Comment: @Tiramonium the problem is — when I debug my application on PC that's part of domain it consider itself authenticated into my domain. I don't want that

Comment: So, explain your question further, you want database authentication only or you want both to be an option?

Comment: only database authentication

Answer (score 0):

In IIS Manager, navigate to your web site.  Double-click the **Authentication** icon and make sure that only **Anonymous Authentication** is enabled.  I am guessing that you have **Windows Authentication** enabled.

Comment: There is no IIS installed locally, only IIS express as part of VS